# How to handle nil class while opening a link using watir

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to open an link if its href is defined but getting undefined method error. Below is the code

```
def click_link(elementName, elementType, browser)
begin
  case elementType #Check the first byte of the response code.
    when 'class' then
      browser.a(:class, elementName).when_present.click
      return ''
    when 'id' then
      browser.a(:id, elementName).when_present.click
      return ''
    when 'value' then
      browser.a(:value, elementName).when_present.click
      return ''
    when 'text' then
      browser.a(:text, elementName).when_present.click
      return ''
    when 'onclick' then
      browser.a(:onclick, elementName).when_present.click
      return ''
    when 'href' then
      browser.p(:class, "create_button").a(:href, "?type=1").when_present.click
      return ''
    else return "link Not Found"
  end
rescue Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException,
  Watir::Exception::ObjectDisabledException,
  Watir::Exception::ObjectReadOnlyException,
  Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException,
  Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException,
  Watir::Exception::UnknownCellException,
  Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException,
  Watir::Exception::NoStatusBarException,
  Watir::Exception::NavigationException,
  Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException,
  Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException,
  Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError => e
  errorMessage = "cannot Find Element: " + elementType+ ": " + elementName
  return errorMessage
end

end
```

Im getting this error = undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. Where Im going wrong

Thanks!

Comment: I am getting error only for href case else are working fine

Comment: What is the link you are trying to click? A href of just "?type=1" seems a bit unusual. Is that the full href or just a part? If it is a part, you need to use a regular expression to do the matching. For example `a(:href, /\?type=1/`.